# Using NX with no PasswordAuthentication SSH setup

Tags: nx

I'm trying to setup passwordless SSH access.

My username is bmccann, so in /etc/ssh/sshd_config I added:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowUsers bmccann nx
```

I ran ssh-keygen on the client and put ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub from the client into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server.

I can now login with no password using the ssh command.  However, I can no longer access the machine via NX as long as /etc/ssh/sshd_config has "PasswordAuthentication no".

Server error logs:

```
$ grep NX /var/log/messages
Feb 11 01:25:51 bmccann-htpc NXSERVER-3.4.0-12[23552]: ERROR: Failed authentication. NXSsh exit status is:255 'NXNssUserManager::auth'
Feb 11 01:25:51 bmccann-htpc NXSERVER-3.4.0-12[23552]: Failed SSHd authentication for user 'bmccann', to '127.0.0.1', port '22': 'NX> 204 Authentication failed.\n ' 'NXNssUserManager::auth'
Feb 11 01:25:51 bmccann-htpc NXSERVER-3.4.0-12[23552]: ERROR: Error while trying to authenticate user:bmccann. NXNssUserManager::auth returned 255 'NXShell::handler_login'
Feb 11 01:25:51 bmccann-htpc NXSERVER-3.4.0-12[23552]: ERROR: failed 'sshd authentication' for user 'bmccann' from '108.29.137.64'. NXShell::handler_login NXShell 373
```

What do I need to do to restore my NX access?  Is there something I need to setup in the NX client so that it no longer asks me for a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to get NX to stop prompting me for a password, but the following worked to allow a password to be used with NX:

```
EnableUserDB = "1"
EnablePasswordDB = "1"
sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --useradd bmccann
```

I added [more details on my blog](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/security-lockdown-for-linux/).

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to do to restore my NX access?

Bring back the change in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart OpenSSH server.

Use password or [authorized keys](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/FreeNX). Empty passwords not allowed with PAM authentication.

Comment: I ran ssh-keygen on the client.

Then I put ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub from the client into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on server.

Is that what you mean by authorized keys or do you mean that I need to enter a passphrase when I run ssh-keygen?

Comment: No, passphrase not needed. Test ssh from client to server: ssh -vvv server

Comment: Hmm, I am using authorized keys without a passphrase, so I'm not sure what's wrong.  I've updated the question to make that clearer and provide some more details.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: AllowUsers myusername nx bmccann

Comment: I only put myusername as an example because I wasn't sure it would be obvious my username was bmccann.  I actually have "AllowUsers bmccann nx" in the file.  Sorry for the confusion.  I've clarified above.